# Ubuntu 16.04: Tomcat 8 won't start with setenv.sh

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I have created a `setenv.sh` file in my `tomcat8/bin` directory with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ENVARS for Tomcat
#
export CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat8"

export CATALINA_BASE="/usr/share/tomcat8"

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"

# TDS specific ENVARS
#
# Define where the TDS content directory will live
#   THIS IS CRITICAL and there is NO DEFAULT - the
#   TDS will not start without this.
#
CONTENT_ROOT=-Dtds.content.root.path=/var/lib/tomcat8/content

# set java prefs related variables (used by the wms service, for example)
JAVA_PREFS_ROOTS="-Djava.util.prefs.systemRoot=$CATALINA_HOME/content/thredds/javaUtilPrefs \
                  -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=$CATALINA_HOME/content/thredds/javaUtilPrefs"

#
# Some commonly used JAVA_OPTS settings:
#
NORMAL="-d64 -Xmx4096m -Xms512m -server -ea"
HEAP_DUMP="-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
HEADLESS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

#
# Standard setup.
#
JAVA_OPTS="$CONTENT_ROOT $NORMAL $MAX_PERM_GEN $HEAP_DUMP $HEADLESS $JAVA_PREFS_ROOTS"

export JAVA_OPTS
```

Unfortunately tomcat won't start after saving this file:

```
tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Do 2016-05-26 16:45:51 CEST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5903 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mai 26 16:45:46 student systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
Mai 26 16:45:46 student tomcat8[5903]:  * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat8
Mai 26 16:45:51 student tomcat8[5903]:    ...fail!
Mai 26 16:45:51 student systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mai 26 16:45:51 student systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
Mai 26 16:45:51 student systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mai 26 16:45:51 student systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I need this configuration for an external server application (thredds data server). I suppose it could be something wrong about the JAVA_HOME variable. I copied the path which i found out with `sudo update-alternatives --config java` (see [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)).

Can someone tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre` as JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: 1. is your `setenv.sh` executable? 2. You should set `CATALINA_OPTS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points to fix my issues:

1. In the `setenv.sh` file, i forgot to put the value for `content_root` between quotation marks:

`CONTENT_ROOT="-Dtds.content.root.path=/var/lib/tomcat8/content"`

2. I had to change writing permissions for this folder:

`sudo chmod a+rwx /var/lib/tomcat8/content/`

Answer (score 6):

I found this question because I was getting a similar error message.  After doing some digging, I found that  `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh` is completely ignored by the services script that starts tomcat:   `/etc/init.d/tomcat8`. Instead, it looks at environment settings in `/etc/default/tomcat8`.

This means that even though tomcat starts with the JVM specified in setenv.sh, the init script fails to see it running because it is expecting a different JVM to be used.

Instead of setting `JAVA_HOME` in *setenv.sh*, set it in `/etc/default/tomcat8`.  At this point, I have deleted *setenv.sh* altogether and put all my tomcat settings in */etc/*.

Edit: Since I wrote this answer, I have since migrated to Tomcat 9.  The same thing applies to this latest version under Ubuntu.  Here are the current contents of my `/etc/default/tomcat9`:

```
# The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at least
# JDK version 8. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for
# OpenJDK and the Oracle JDK are tried.
JAVA_HOME=`readlink -f  /usr/bin/javac | sed 's|/bin/javac||g'`

# You may pass JVM startup parameters to Java here. If unset, the default
# options will be: -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseG1GC
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```